# How to use Tensorflow for Android in Qt (QML) app?

Tags: android, c++, qt, tensorflow, qml

**Context**

I work on an app for Android which should analyse in real time the camera input.
I chose Qt to develop the user interface, for portability reasons (the app may evolve to support other platforms than Android).

For image processing, my colleague is working on it using [TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/).

*So I want to know how could I use TensorFlow for Android in Qt ?*

**What I've done :**

- Downloaded tensorflow the nightly precompiled version (#453) from http://ci.tensorflow.org/view/Nightly/job/nightly-android/lastSuccessfulBuild as suggered at https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/mobile/linking_libs#android (option 2)
- Put the files in my qt project `android/libs` folder
- Modified my *.pro file to add :

  - the given *.jar file with : `DISTFILES += android_v453/libandroid_tensorflow_inference_java.jar`
  - the given *.so file with : `ANDROID_EXTRA_LIBS = $$PWD/android/libs/armeabi-v7a/libtensorflow_inference.so`

But for now I'm confused. How should I call it in my Qt App ?

*Note : I just noticed that TensorFlow Android interface is aimed **only at inference**, so no training would be available.* ([source](https://www.tensorflow.org/mobile/android_build#android_inference_library))

Comment: Isn't tensorflow quite processor hungry to run on an Android device?
Why wouldn't you consider running it on a server and using the android device only for input output.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.

Yes, this option (tensorflow on server) is considered as the first choice of development, because we know that it might be heavy for an Android device. 

But it would be great if we could just integrate TensorFlow within the app, to use it without internet for example. 

I want to try to integrate it to simply know if it's a possibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I think I figured it out !

The [QAndroidJniEnvironment](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qandroidjnienvironment.html) & [QAndroidJniObject](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qandroidjniobject.html) classes from [Qt AndroidExtras](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtandroidextras-index.html) seems to do all the big work.

Sample instanciation code:

```
QAndroidJniObject graph ("org/tensorflow/Graph");
QAndroidJniObject inferenceInterface("org/tensorflow/contrib/android/TensorFlowInferenceInterface", "(Lorg/tensorflow/Graph;)V", graph.object());
```

I know this works because tensorflow now logs data to the Qt console.